# Make menhir add user-defined functions from .mly to .mli

Tags: ocaml, menhir

Menhir allows to add arbitrary ocaml code to the end of the .mly file, where I want to declare a few functions. But I could not find a way to make menhir add my functions to the .mli file, so that they are visible from the other modules. Is it possible?

Comment: Related question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38514226

Answer (score 2):

The answer is simple, it's *no*. The code defined in the `.mly` file is only used by the parser.

As stated in the manual :

> A header is a piece of OCaml code, surrounded with
>   %{
>   and
>   %}
>   . It is copied verbatim at the beginning of the
>   .ml
>   file.

Comment: They also allow trailing code that goes in the end of the .ml file. One could think that it is a good place to put some helper functions for the client code, but apparently no luck here.